# Sorting rows within a section in a UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, sorting

I'd like to sort my items within a section of a UITableView. So in the below screenshot under the "N/A" section "Dad" would need to come first followed by "Hi". In the "Last 7d" section the items would also need to be sorted alphabetically.

[image]

I can't figure out where in the table's lifecycle to sort the items. Sorting my model (the list of items) and using it with the UITableView doesn't seem to help.

**EDIT**

Please find below my code. I now understand that the best thing to do is to not only sort but also filter my items into separate lists, one for each displayed section. This is better from a performance perspective, since `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` keeps getting called for each displayed item. Eventhough it doesn't get called for the overall total number of items, it would still be sloppy to sort over and over again the master list of items each time a new item is displayed.

My concern is that the number of sections can vary dynamically and it could reach quite a high number (up to 8). The grouping into sections can also vary - either sections by priority or by due date. So, I think I need to create a more complex data structure for my model -- instead of the current simple list and functions that filter it and sort it at "display time" a class with multiple sorted lists, one for each section, maybe. I will need to create several of these classes, depending on what the user groups by. And these classes will also need to have custom functions to find in the model the item that was tapped / updated based on the indexPath. Makes sense though.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Since I register the TableViewCell class to be used to create a new table view cell in viewDidLoad(), when tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: next needs a table cell, your new class will be used automatically.
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        // special case for empty, "add reminder" cell
        cell.toDoItem = nil

        if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section >= ReminderDue.sections.count {
            return cell
        }

        // If a proper reminder is chosen
        if let definiteList = self.groupByDelegator.getReminderList() {

            // Take the master list of items and return a filtered sublist of items that belong to that section
            let sectionItems = ReminderDue.getReminders(definiteList, inSection: ReminderDue.sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section])



            // Do the sorting here
            let QUERY_SETTINGS_KEY = "querysettings"
            if let definiteIndex = reminderListController.indexOfDisplayedCalInMenu {
                let definiteSetting = loadQuerySetting(definiteIndex, saveKey: QUERY_SETTINGS_KEY)
                sectionItems.sortBy(definiteSetting.sortBy)
            }

            cell.selectionStyle = .none     // This gets rid of the highlighting that happens when you select a table cell.

            // If a reminder (i.e., not the empty row at the end.)
            if !sectionItems.list.isEmpty && (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row < sectionItems.count {
                //            cell.delegate = self
                cell.delegate = updateReminderDelegate      // Assign as the TableViewCell's delegate the ReminderMainVC (via its UpdateReminderDelegate)

                let rem = sectionItems.list[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
                cell.toDoItem = rem
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: you need to sort the model and then reload table.

Comment: *"Sorting my model (the list of items) and using it with the UITableView doesn't seem to help"* - show that code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Sorting the model is the way to do this. The table view is for displaying the data, not for sorting directly. You’ll need a clever sorting closure though, that checks for whichever property of your data items is being used to assign items to a section. I’ll have a think!

Comment: Can you share your `cellForRow` method? It depends a little on how you are populating the tableview. You could simply sort your array of data by the objects’ names, then filter it by your section headings when making the cells for each section. Due to the stable sorting algorithm, the cells in each section will then be sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven’t shared your code so I can’t use your specific values, but here is an example. I’m assuming you have an array of objects that is used to populate the tableview and that these objects have a property for their section ("low" or "none" priority in your case) and one for their visible name value ("Vic’s" or "Dad" as examples in your case).

**Edit**: With thanks to @rmaddy

You should sort the array first by the name property and then filter it into a new array for each section. Because this is a stable sorting algorithm, the alphabetic order of the names will persist. Do this when you Load your data, which might be in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // mainArray is your array of data model objects. You will need a strong reference to it  and the section arrays so declare them at the top of your view controller class.

    // This will sort your array by name
    mainArray.sort() { $0.name < $1.name }

    // Setup section arrays (I have assumed your objects have a property called priority

    // No priority
    noPriorityArray = mainArray.filter() { $0.priority == "none" }

    // Low priority
    lowPriorityArray = mainArray.filter() { $0.priority == "low" }
}
```

Then access these arrays in the tableview delegate method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell... // Put your code for getting cell here

    // Now code to get cell for each section
    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        // No priority
        cell.textLabel.text = noPriorityArray[indexPath.row]?.name

    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

        // Low priority
        cell.textLabel.text = lowPriorityArray[indexPath.row]?.name
    }

    // Other code for other sections or other setup etc.

    return cell
}
```

Comment: The data structures should all be organized long before `cellForRowAt` is called. `cellForRowAt` is called over and over. It makes no sense to update the data model over and over just to get the right data for the current cell. Sort and filter the data once when the data is loaded.

Comment: @rmaddy What would you recommend? Would it be better to do data structure setup in `viewDidLoad()` making filter d arrays per section, then just reference these in `cellForRow()`?

Comment: As I said, the data should be sorted and filtered when the data is loaded, where ever that loading takes place. By the time a single table view data source method is called, the data model must already be in the proper state.

Comment: That's better. But until the OP provides more detail, this question isn't even worth trying to answer. Put your effort into worthwhile questions.

Comment: Question: since I have multiple ways of grouping data depending on the users preference should my data model consist of 1) A master list of items that is ungrouped AND 2) a class of lists for each grouping/section? I need the master list to load the data initially, etc. Basically I'm then keeping multiple copies of my data.

Comment: @Daniel Yes I would keep a master list which is ungrouped. You could maybe just have one other list and sort, filter or group it in a `switch` statement depending on user’s preference. Don’t worry too much about having more than one copy, provided there is a logical reason for it. If your data model is a `class` (a reference type), additional arrays will only hold a reference to the objects anyway. The objects themselves should not be duplicated.

Comment: @Daniel I was reading your edit. There would be other ways to do this with a more complex data model, but I’m not sure of what the best practices would be. As long as sorting and filtering is not done in `cellForRow()` it would be okay to do it when view loads or in a method when user chooses an alternative way to display the data, before reloading the table view.

Answer (score 0):

```
let sortedItems = arrayOfItems.sorted(by: <)
```